# POM (point-or-marker) in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to use functions `org-entry-properties` and `org-id-get`, both of which use an optional argument `pom`. For example, `org-entry-properties` documentation says:

> Get all properties of the entry at point-or-marker POM.

[Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html) almost doesn't mention the word "marker", however there are several functions ending with `-marker`. Now i have several questions about it.

1. What is that point-or-marker?
2. Is it the same as mark in a mark ring?
3. How do i get a marker in an org-mode buffer?
4. How do i use this marker in the above functions invocation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An (absolute) position in a buffer is given by a number, which is roughly the number of characters that are before that position. Markers, on the other hand, allow to mark a "relative position" in the buffer : if you add text before it, it moves forward (like it were an invisible, 0-width, character).

At any time, you can convert a marker to an (absolute) position (an integer). That is why many arguments want a POM: they want a position, but accept that it is given as a marker.

The "mark" in emacs, is one specific marker which is easy to access by appropriate key chords (C-SPC sets it, C-x C-x exchanges the mark and the point, etc.).
The/a "mark ring" is the history of all previous "mark" markers (either in a given buffer, which is the local mark ring, or globally, for the so called global mark ring).

More info in the elisp manual :

- from within emacs : (info "(elisp) Markers")
- on the web : http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Markers.html

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the Emacs Manual, take a look at the [Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Markers.html) for more information on markers:

> A marker is a Lisp object used to specify a position in a buffer
>   relative to the surrounding text. A marker changes its offset from the
>   beginning of the buffer automatically whenever text is inserted or
>   deleted, so that it stays with the two characters on either side of
>   it.

The POM element to the functions you mention can thus either be a marker, i.e., a lisp object that contains both a buffer and a position in that buffer, or simply a position. In the first case, the functions will first switch to the buffer of the marker and move `point` to the marker's position before executing the rest of the function.

In the second case, it will stay in the current buffer, but move `point` to the given position before executing the rest of the function.

That is, the function is executed relative to the given buffer/position. At the end of the function's body, the original location of the `point` is restored.